# Issue: Insufficient authorization Arcgis pro

Tags: postgresql, geometry, arcgis, arcmap

On ArcGIS Pro I connected to a PostgreSQL database. In the database, I have  tables that when I want to open I get the following issue of 'insufficient authorization'. When I try to open other tables, I get another issue of 'layer not found'. I looked online and saw it might be that there is a privilege applied on somee of the tables and not on others.

Can you please tell me what the issue might be and how I can solve it?